# how to do a clean pull request on github?

Tags: git, github, branch, commit, pull-request

On github i'm using the `master` as the working branch and a `dev` which is the one where i work on the files.

Recently I made a pull request from dev to `master` and I merged it fine... but the pull request is equivalent to 1 commit and therefore now, "`master` is 1 commit ahead of `dev`".

So if I start to commit to `dev` again i will find myself in the situation "10 commit ahead, 1 commit behind `master`".

If I repeat the process of pull request to `master` and keep committing to `dev` I will find myself in "10 commit ahead, 5 commit behind `master`" situation... which is quite frustrating...

What can I do to avoid this? should I remove the `dev` branch any time I do a pull request to `master` (which is quite annoying)? should I do a counter pull request from `master` to `dev` just after the "real" pull request (which looks really ugly)?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your branch to be at the top of master, you want to rebase it.
First, fetch the master branch (if it's remote), then simply do `git rebase master`

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: but i don't want to change master... only the dev branch

Comment: ok this works for my case: `git rebase master dev`. in this way dev will become equal to master